# Insert jQuery Calender in a "Foreach" Statement Gridview

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, foreach, jquery-ui-datepicker

This is my php coding for the gridview table which has multiple rows of date input

```
 foreach ($form_data['srms'] AS $srms) {
     echo '<tr>' . "\n";
     echo '<td><input type="text" id="datepicker" name="srms[date][]" value="'.$srms['date'].'"></td>' . "\n";
     echo '<td>';
```

This is my js Coding

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" }).val();
    });
</script>
```

The problem is, the datepicker only comes out on the first text input box when clicked.
It does not appear on the following text input boxes..
How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs must be unique. Use a class instead:

```
echo '<td><input type="text" class="datepicker" name="srms[date][]" value="'.$srms['date'].'"></td>' . "\n";
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" }).val();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks!! It works like a gem! btw, the date will be captured as it it right?